# Load more button push element up not down in angular app

Tags: angular, performance, asp.net-core, ngfor, qpushbutton

I have a angular application. Till today it works fine in google chrome but today when i click the load more button load more button is still there and push every time 10 product on the top. It mean when we click a more button some data load and more button goes down by scrolling we can load again but in my case load more button always on screen and product load it's top. Scroll position change and keep position always on load button. But in Microsoft Edge it's work fine.
Could you please help me to solve this problem.
[image]

### my html here..

```
 <mat-card class="mb-2">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let i = index;">
                        <div class="row pad-20" *ngIf="(i % 2 === 0)">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mouse-hover d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <img class="cart-deatils-img" mat-card-image
                                    src=" 
                            {{appHost.hostName}}images/fruitImages/{{fruit?.fileName[0]}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 vertically-center">
                                <mat-card-content>
                                    <br />
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="display-2 shadow-text text-center font-weight>
                                            {{fruit?.name}}
                                        </span>
                                        <span>(<span *ngFor="let star of getFullStar(fruit?.rating)"
                                                class="material-icons color-orange font-13">
                                                grade
                                            </span>
                                            <span *ngFor="let star of getOutlineStar(fruit?.rating)"
                                                class="material-icons color-orange font-13">
                                                star_border
                                            </span>)
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span *ngIf="!fruit?.isActive" class="badge badge-warning 
                                               shadow-text text-center font-weight-bold my-3">
                                            Unavailabe
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-4 font-13">
                                        <span>
                                            {{fruit?.description}}
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="no-decoration font-13"
                                        routerLink="/general-user/fruit/details/{{fruit?.id}}">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn"
                                            aria-label="Example icon button with a filter list icon">
                                            <mat-icon>call_missed_outgoing</mat-icon>
                                        </button> <span style="padding: 10px;">SEE DETAILS</span>
                                    </a>
                                </mat-card-content>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-4 pad-20" *ngIf="!(i % 2 === 0)">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 vertically-center">
                                <mat-card-content>
                                    <br />
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="display-2 shadow-text text-center font-weight- 
                                           bold my-3">
                                            {{fruit?.name}}
                                        </span>
                                        <span>(<span *ngFor="let star of getFullStar(fruit?.rating)"
                                                class="material-icons color-orange font-13">
                                                grade
                                            </span>
                                            <span *ngFor="let star of getOutlineStar(fruit?.rating)"
                                                class="material-icons color-orange font-13">
                                                star_border
                                            </span>)
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span *ngIf="fruit?.isActive" class="badge badge-success 
                            shadow-text text-center font-weight-bold my-3">
                                            Availabe
                                        </span>
                                        <span *ngIf="!fruit?.isActive">
                                            Unavailabe
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-4 font-13">
                                        <span>
                                            {{fruit?.description}}
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="no-decoration font-13"
                                        routerLink="/general-user/fruit/details/{{fruit?.id}}">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn"
                                            aria-label="Example icon button with a filter list icon">
                                            <mat-icon>call_missed_outgoing</mat-icon>
                                        </button> <span style="padding: 10px;">SEE DETAILS</span>
                                    </a>
                                </mat-card-content>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mouse-hover d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <img class="cart-deatils-img" mat-card-image
                                    src=" 
                                {{appHost.hostName}}images/fruitImages/{{fruit?.fileName[0]}}">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                    <div *ngIf="!noMore" class="mb-1 mt-4 font-roboto row d-flex justify-content- 
                   center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn-not-focus" mat-raised-button style="

background: #F25C05; color: white; width: 250px;
                    font-size: 15px;" (click)="onLoadMore()">
                                <span *ngIf="!isProgress" class="material-icons icon-vertical">
                                    hourglass_empty
                                </span>
                                <span *ngIf="!isProgress" class="font-with-text"> Load More 
  Fruit</span>
                                <span *ngIf="isProgress" class="processing-span">Loading Fruit 
   Wait...
                                    <mat-spinner [diameter]="30" class="spinner-sapn"></mat-spinner>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
```

## and my load more function is here

```
    onLoadMore(){
        this.isProgress = true;
        this.fruitService.getByCount(this.fruits.length).subscribe((res: any) => {
          if (res.obj != null) {
            let fruit = res.obj;
            let length = fruit.length;
            if(length < 4){
              this.noMore = true;
            }
            for(let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++){
              this.fruits.push(fruit[i]);
            }
          }
          this.isProgress = false;
        }, e =>{      
          this.isProgress = false;
          this.noMore = true;
        });
      }
```

## and I load every route here

```
    <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container font-roboto">
      <!-- <mat-sidenav [opened]="showAllTabNav" #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport> -->
      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <div>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue recently in React with Chrome.

A Hotfix for now is to add `overflow-anchor: none;` to the CSS of the button, or even the container of the content

I answered in more detail here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327574/14062868